# Why do loopsticks and chokes receive RFs equally well?

Tags: rf, inductor, amplitude-modulation

In response to answers from my previous question, I compared the ability of a tank circuit to receive signals when the inductor was a loopstick vs a choke.

The inductor was either a) a choke with Lc=0.54mH (R=3.2ohms) (as in figure 1), or b) a loopstick with Ll=0.6mH (R=8.3 ohms)) (Figure 3, from a radio clock).

**Finding f0**.
A sinusoidal 1V (p2p) signal from a signal generator was injected across the whole circuit shown in Figure 2. The frequency was adusted to maximise the voltage across the tank circuit, to find the resonant frequency, which was found to be f0=40kHz (for both the choke and the loopstick).

As an aside: The measured p2p amplitude across the tank circuit at f0 was 57mV,  so that

57mV/1000mV = Z/(Z+20k),

so, solving for Z yields Z = 1200 ohms at f0.

Finally, I disconnected the scope and R1 from the circuit, and used the scope to generate an RF signal at f0 through a long wire antenna. I then measured the amplitude V induced across the tank circuit at a short distance (4 inches) from the antenna.

Result: With the loopstick, Vl = 4mV, whereas with the choke, Vc = 3mV.

This seems to suggest that both the choke and the loospstick are almost equaly good (bad) at converting the RF signal into voltage.

What am I missing? Are the results for the choke and loopstick similar because the circuit is recording a ceiling/floor effect (ie it is a rubbish circuit)?

[image] Figure 1. Picture of a (very) spare choke, with the plastic coating removed (I managed to break the wires inside in the process of removing the plastic). The material at both ends (caps) of the coiled wire is magnetic (ferrite?).

[image]
Figure 2.
Circuit used to estimate resonant frequency f0 and impedance Z of tank circuit at resonant frequency f0.

[image]
Figure 3. Loopstick used to replace choke in tank circuit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That "long wire" is electrically short, and almost all the field around it is electric.  Additionally, you aren't measuring radiation, you're in the near field where electric and magnetic fields aren't balanced; in particular, E-field greatly exceeds H-field.  You have an equivalent circuit more like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f87mpS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

from which it's easy to see why the inductors perform comparably.

A better test would be to use a magnetic loop, at calibrated distance so that both coils experience the same magnetic field.  This will again be near-field and E/H imbalanced, but the H field is the whole point of the loopstick, so it makes sense to pair it with a loop for probing purposes.

Put another way: you've detected more E than H, proving that your purportedly-H-field-only probes, in fact, are not, and are rather poorly shielded against E-field "interference".  Wrapping them in foil, minus a slit to allow magnetic field to enter, and connecting the foil to ground, would improve things significantly; in that case, you might get a small signal with either coil held close to the "long wire", but as the displacement current flowing into it will be small, I don't expect the magnetic field is noticeable either.

Comment: I think you have just confirmed my suspicion (stated in my question) that my circuit is rubbish for comparing loopsticks with chokes. But from a practical perspective, my receiver is used to detect RF only when it is close (< 2m) to the long wire transmitter antenna; and for this particular application, it looks as if there is no advantage to using a loopstick.

Answer (score 0):

> *Finally, I disconnected the scope and R1 from the circuit, and used
> the scope to generate an RF signal at f0 through a long wire antenna.
> I then measured the amplitude V induced across the tank circuit at a
> short distance (4 inches) from the antenna.*

At circa 40 kHz a monopole antenna would need to be nearly 2 km long to generate a reasonable magnetic field. What you are generating is a decent electric field (in the near-field) that capacitively couples to both coils about the same. This is not the way to test a loop-stick antenna vs drum core.